# XML-RPC , specifying a category when pinging a blog?

Tags: php, web-services, codeigniter, blogs, xml-rpc

I'm using codeigniter xml-rpc library to ping different blogs,

```
$this->xmlrpc->server('bloglines.com/ping', 80);
$this->xmlrpc->method('weblogUpdates.ping');
$request = array('My Blog', 'http://www.myblog.com');
$this->xmlrpc->request($request);
```

Questions:
1- How can I provide a category for the blog ?
2- if a xml-rpc service supports webUpdates.extendedping , why should I use it instead of he simple .ping method? 
3- Should I ping the newly created blog post URL, or the main blog URL (Then the service  will spider the whole blog for changes?)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

1 you can create associative array any nesting to send data to server

```
$request = array('name' => 'My Blog', 
                 'url' => 'http://www.myblog.com',
                 'category' => 'your category');
```

2 you can create webUpdates.anyMethodName оn "server" controller, and request it from client.

Are you sure you need xml-rpc to ping some urls (the purpose of this library client-server  information exchange) ? maybe Curl more appropriate for your task or utility like linkchecker